# Two Users Have More Than 80 Edits on Posts, but No Strunk and White Badge?

Tags: support, editing, badges

I noticed for the last few days that two users have enough edits for the silver Strunk and White badge, but the badges have not been awarded.

Is this a bug?

https://pm.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edits on your own posts don't count.  Edits that only change tags do not count.  If you take these into account, there are less than 80 edits that count.

For more details, see [this Meta Stack Overflow post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) with all the specifics about badge requirements.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.